# Typescript type inference and optional object property

Tags: typescript, constructor, option-type, record, inference

Basically what I want to achieve is to have class X infer its K type from the provided constructor argument typing.

I have written this:

```
interface XContstructorParams<K extends string = never> {
    record?: Record<K, number>;
    // Other stuff with some being optionals, which is why it's all in single
    // object, as I don't want to do new X(arg1, undefined, undefined, arg2)
}

class X<K extends string = never> {
    private record: Record<K, number>;
    constructor(params: XContstructorParams<K>) {
        // I'd rather avoid to use a type assertion here but it's not a big deal
        // compared to the issue below.
        this.record = params.record || {} as Record<K, number>;
    }
    
    getNumber(k: K): number {
        return this.record[k];
    }
}
```

This actually works to infer the type of K to be never when the `record` property is not given, but it does not prevent to manually specify an incorrect value for K:

```
// Correctly inferred to be X<'a', 'b'>
const x1 = new X({ record: {'a': 1, 'b': 2} });
// Correctly inferred to be X<never>
const x2 = new X({});
// Oops ! This is incorrect as `getNumber` will not return a number when called with 'c'
// or 'd ! But it is allowed because of how I wrote the constructor `record` property to
// be optional. I want it to be optional only when K is never. It's either you provided
// a record and it's keys determine K, or you didn't give a record and K is never, but
// should not be able to specify K and not provide a record matching your specified K.
const x3 = new X<'c' | 'd'>({});
```

I'd like x3 to be recognized as a compilation error but I couldn't manage to make it work. What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: for some reason, stack overflow removes my "hello" at the start of the message so... better late than never I guess... Hello and thanks for your help ! ;-)

Comment: Why not `class X<T extends Record<string, number> { getNumber(k: keyof T){} }`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tested your suggestion but `const x3 = new X<Record<'c' | 'd', number>>({});` does not throw an error in that case either.

Comment: Because the `record` property of the parameter is optional, it is simply instantiated with whatever type corresponds to the explicit type argument when the property is omitted from the argument

Comment: So you are saying that what I am trying to do (that is get a compiler error for x3) is impossible ?

Comment: It _is_ possible to ensure an error is raised, via one of several methods, but I'm not entirely sure why the property is optional In the first place. It seems like a contradiction. `constructor(params: XContstructorParams<K> = {record: {}})` where `record` is required in XContstructorParams<K>` instead.

Comment: The reason it is optional is that I don't want to specify it when it is empty. It may seem weird in this small example but it makes sense in the rest of the codebase. Basically, the "feature" of this record property is optional. If a record was specified for this object, you can use `getNumber` with one of the valid keys. If no record was specified then there is no value that is valid to use with `getNumber`. If the property is not optional then I would have to do `new X({ ...otherProps, record: {} });` where `new X({ ...otherProps })` would otherwise suffice.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoGED24DOYoCuCYmUACnFHALY4A8AKshAB6QgAmOyAShAqQ508UUAHMANMhAFqAI2gA+RcgDeAKGRbkUfoID8ALmQN1AX3XqEAGzg5uqOgGlmbCJ24jxyAD7SIAG7QyAC8-kFQUmShajp6UBzGLqzsXMheIGLI+rzxQk5SMvJKyMZ8Agl0IIHQhbIKUCpmKhrayAAOogFwkHEVibn9znXFjQDcmtoCICJEJFAAFO2UNDjGGNhgs8SkFFS0dOWCw9L1SioAZMhkAJRqk21aYAAWwDgAdLr9Mcv7H1+CXx+VRmZB2QbHAqnUaKCZtCwPZBiCBgAByZ0WAGskjdjEUGvdHtpdGACFAQMgXm9PnkANqYgC6cO0FgRVmweGQLAAjDFqgB3NALVR9QTGEUAcjgEuM3KkErkMuQACZkKCzDcJuyZmAuaqwgKhSDNdrOSwAMx8iCCxwShAS3zICUcCWKYUasZAA? A bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Is this solution works for you?

```js
interface XContstructorParams<K extends string = never> {
  record: K extends never ? undefined : Record<K, number>;
  // Other stuff with some being optionals, which is why it's all in single
  // object, as I don't want to do new X(arg1, undefined, undefined, arg2)
}

class X<K extends string = never> {
  private record: Record<K, number>;
  constructor(params: XContstructorParams<K>) {
    // I don't think you need type castin here
    this.record = params.record
  }

  getNumber(k: K): number {
    return this.record[k];
  }
}


// Correctly inferred to be X<'a', 'b'>
const x1 = new X({ record: { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 } });
const result = x1.getNumber('a') // number

const x2 = new X<never>({}); // error


const x3 = new X<'c' | 'd'>({}); // error
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the answers really sastisfy my needs yet, sorry. The one from Aluan is a bit messy as he put it, and yours forces the `record` property to be present even when `K` is `never`.

In practice, I think I will go with removing the optionality of the `record` property as well. However, just removing the `?` from my original code is enough to solve the original issue. If I have to write `record: undefined` then I might as well be explicit and write `record: {}`. Or am I missing some additional properties of your version ?